# Symfony Entity set all fields nullable by default

Tags: php, symfony

Is it a right decision to set all getter fields nullable by default like

```
/**
 * @return int|null
 */
public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

Explanation for doing it is that you can create entity and call method

```
$entinty = new Entity();
$entity->getId();
```

and it will be fatal error without nullable sign. But why anybody will do such kind of things or there are other side effects?

Is it right thing or overhead?

Answer (score 1):

This depends.

You will not get a fatal error in your example, but does it really make sense? There will never be an ID available at this point so you really should not call it.

This is how I decide to do it:
Does it have to be set? Then even set it to a default value like this

```
public $withDefault = true;

public function getWithDefault(): bool { ... }
```

or enforce a value in the constructor

```
public $enforced;

public function __construct(int $enforced) { $this->enforced = $enforced; }

public function getEnforced(): int { ... }
```

In these cases, the getter does not return null.

For all other cases you should make it dependend on the database field if that is nullable the getter can return null. And if it is not nullable, then the getter should not return null either.

Comment: You are right. But my example is with id (primary key AUTO_INCREMENT), so you can not set default value for this field.
And I don't really understand why some people enforce to set all fields nullable, by reason, that it will be fatal, if you call method on new Entity without nullable sign(?).
As for me it's some kind of noncence, that people will never do with common sence.

Comment: With ID you should never call getId() before you did a persist/flush/triggered insert. So in my opinion the fatal error would be ok.

Comment: Why should you never call getId() before? When I do it, It's to know if the Entity is already persisted or not.

Comment: @FlorianHermann: In an ORM with clean relations, you do not need the ID before you persist. And if an error occurs, don't flush or rollback.